# "Proper" formatting of code eg. where everything should go

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, formatting

So far, this is what I do:

```
<?php

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<meta tags>
<script src>
<title>
<links>
<head>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<html>
<javascript>
<some php>
</body>
```

I realize that some things have to be in a certain order for example, an element has to exist before it can be modified; I'm talking about javscript.

I think that the `<link><meta><title>`etc... have to be in the header... also curious if I need the `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` as well as the language declaration

I think I also realize that pages are parse from top left to bottom right per character. So...

Any help would be appreciated, I'm looking for easy to read formatting so that other people who read the code can pick it up relatively easily <- awful two words

Comment: use documentation either, and stick to the basic rather than finding a best practice approach for DOM.

Comment: meta, title, script, and link tags all belong within the header. Your structure should be HTML tag wrapping HEAD tag and BODY tag: the head containing meta - information, scripts, etc., and the body containing the content of the page

Comment: If you're talking about JavaScript the PHP is irrelevant, JS will only ever see the output. Your HTML structure is ... broken (see @JamesSpence comment). The JS won't *really* be able to do anything with the HTML elements until the DOM is fully loaded so it doesn't matter where you put it you'll not be able to do much with things like `getElementById()` unless you're calling it in a document `onload` event; generally for neatness I'd stick it in the `<head>`. Otherwise about the only time the order of non-displayed elements is important is putting `<meta charset .. />` above `<title>`

Comment: thanks guys for the help, right now I just "modify till it works" which doesn't seem professional, I'd like to make code so that others can be like "Oh yeah, this guy has a clue what he is doing."